# Variadic variadic template template parameters

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, variadic-functions, template-templates

Is there a straightforward way to have variadic variadic template template parameters. For instance consider the following function signature

```
template<template<typename,size_t...> class Pack, 
  typename T, size_t ... Args>
void foo(const Pack<T,Args...>& a);
```

If we want to pass two `Pack`s we have to now do an overload

```
template<template<typename,size_t...> class Pack, 
  typename T, size_t ... Args0, size_t ... Args1>
void foo(const Pack<T,Args0...>& a, const Pack<T,Args1...>& b);
```

Now what if we want to pass a variable number of objects of `Pack` with different variadic parameters e.g. `Args0...,Args1...,Args2...`.

So I was thinking if there is a practical way of doing something along the lines of (the following is certainly a sketch representation).

```
template<template<typename,size_t...> ... class Pack, typename T,...>  
void foo(const Pack<T,...> ... packs);
```

Comment: What do you need to do with `T` and `Args`? You'd probably be better off just using `template <typename...Ts>` and writing some simple traits to extract what you need.

Comment: @Klaus actually, yes you can... [See for yourself](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1d822071ce2130bf)

Comment: Why parameters only once? It should be "Variadic variadic template template parameters parameters"

Comment: Lol that was a joke

Answer (score 6):

I would just use a normal variadic template:

```
template<typename... Ts>  
void foo(const Ts&... packs) {

}
```

Then write a trait to extract the type and `size_t`s. You could easily add some helper alias templates to do whatever you fancy.

```
template <typename T> struct extract_args;

template <template <typename, size_t...> class Pack, typename T, size_t... Args> 
struct extract_args<Pack<T,Args...>> {
    using type = T;
    using args = std::index_sequence<Args...>;
};
```

Then within `foo` you can extract the arguments and use them however you like. For example, to get a `std::tuple` containing all the `T`s from the packs:

```
using all_ts = std::tuple<typename extract_args<Ts>::type...>;
```

Answer (score 4):

I propose you to manage `Pack` arguments recursively, in this way

```
#include <array>

template <typename T, std::size_t ... Args>
struct  testS
 { };

void foo ()
 { /* terminal iteration */ }

template <template <typename, std::size_t...> class Pack,
          typename T, std::size_t ... Args, typename ... Packs>  
void foo (const Pack<T, Args...> pack0, Packs ... packs)
 { 
   // do something with pack0

   foo(packs...);
 }

int main()
 {
   foo(testS<int>{}, std::array<long, 5U>{}, testS<char, 7U, 9U, 11U>{});

   return 0;
 }
```

**--- Edit ---**

Modified example to show the use with different types and a variable number of `std::size_t` template parameters.

Comment: This solution actually works pretty well. You can invoke `foo` with multiple template types, including ones that (unlike `std::array`) take more than one `size_t` template parameter.

Comment: @Smeeheey - exactly: works with multiple template types with variable `std::size_t` number of template parameters. I've modified the example trying to underline it. Thanks.